# .netCore Startup class not called in Azure Timer Function

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have an Azure Function that I developed using an HTTP trigger. The function would start up, call an api, initialise a DBcontext and write that data from the API to the DB.

It all worked fine, but I needed to make a change and deploy the function using a timer trigger instead. Now, since this change was made, the Startup.cs class is no longer called so there isn't a context injected and it obviously falls over when the context is called inside the function.

Here's a breakdown of the Startup class in my project:

```cs
// using statements

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.FunctionAPI.Startup))]
namespace MyNamespace.FunctionAPI
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        private static string development = FunctionAPIHelper.GetEnvironmentVariable("development");
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            string SqlConnection = "";
            if (development.Equals("yes"))
            {
                SqlConnection = FunctionAPIHelper.GetSqlAzureConnectionString("TestConnectionString");
            }
            else
            {
                SqlConnection = FunctionAPIHelper.GetSqlAzureConnectionString("ConnectionString");
            }

            var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
            CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken ctoken = source.Token;

            builder.Services.AddDbContext<Database.FunctionAPIContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(new SqlConnection
                {
                    ConnectionString = SqlConnection,
                    AccessToken = credential.GetTokenAsync(
                        new TokenRequestContext(
                            new[] { "https://database.windows.net//.default" }), ctoken)
                                .Result.Token
                }
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

Then the Azure Function code using the HTTP Trigger is below. This works as expected when posting to the endpoint it opens up.

```cs
// using statements

namespace MyNamespace.FunctionAPI
{
    public class FunctionAPITrigger
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        private readonly FunctionAPIContext _functionAPIContext;

        public FunctionAPITrigger(FunctionAPIContext functionAPIContext)
        {
            _functionAPIContext = functionAPIContext;
        }

        [FunctionName("FunctionAPITrigger")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]
                HttpRequest req,
                ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("HTTP Trigger received.");

            // do API calls here

            // get stuff from the db
            List<FunctionDBItems> functionDBItems = _functionAPIContext.FunctionDBItems.ToList();

            // do this to the DB items

            _functionAPIContext.SaveChanges();
            
            return new OkObjectResult("DB updated!");
        }
    }
}
```

And now the function code when using a timer trigger and then calling the function manually using the Azure Function extension within VS Code.

```cs
// using statements

namespace MyNamespace.FunctionAPI
{
    public class FunctionAPITrigger
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        private readonly FunctionAPIContext _functionAPIContext;

        public FunctionAPITrigger(FunctionAPIContext functionAPIContext)
        {
            _functionAPIContext = functionAPIContext;
        }

        [FunctionName("PetitionsAPITrigger")]
        public async void Run([TimerTrigger("0 10 12 * * 1-5")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("HTTP Trigger received.");

            // do API calls here

            // get stuff from the db
            List<FunctionDBItems> functionDBItems = _functionAPIContext.FunctionDBItems.ToList();

            // do this to the DB items

            _functionAPIContext.SaveChanges();
            
            log.LogInformation("DB Updated and such");
        }
    }
}
```

The above code now crashes when it reaches the DB call to list the items in the table. Again, the function is triggered by going to the Azure Functions Extension in VS Code, right clicking the function and selecting Execute Function.

This is my first project using Azure Functions, so I'm thinking that maybe there is an issue with the way the Azure Extension triggers timed functions which bypases the `Startup.cs` class.

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: The error itself - Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances. --- Object name "FunctionAPIContext"

Comment: Have you tried removing the static `httpClient` on the timer function? it doesnt appear to be used there

Comment: The client is used inside the portion where I commented `//do API calls here`. That works fine even with a timer and returns data, the problem is the db call. The error sugests that the context was already disposed, but I know that Startup isn't called so it's never actually initiated.